# Exclude autoconfiguration beans based on application yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have some beans that want to exclude from auto configurating based on a configuration on my application.yml file:

```
database:
  enabled: false
```

To do this, I created a Custom exclusion filter to exclude my beans from autoconfigurating:

```
public class DatabaseExclusionFilter implements AutoConfigurationImportFilter {

private static final Set<String> DATABASE_BEANS_SKIP = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration",
                "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"));


@Value("${database.enabled}")
private boolean enabled;

@Override
public boolean[] match(String[] autoConfigurationClasses, AutoConfigurationMetadata autoConfigurationMetadata) {
    List<Boolean> excludeBeans = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!enabled) {
        excludeBeans = match(Arrays.asList(autoConfigurationClasses));
    }
    return convertToPrimitiveArray(excludeBeans);
}
}
```

This way, if the database is disabled in my project, I can exclude the configuration beans to being registered automatically. (This class is also indicated on the spring.factory file on the org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter).

This works fine but I have one problem, I cannot read the values from my yaml file, I think it is a precedence problem, maybe when the **AutoConfigurationImportFilter** is called, the **@Value** is not ready to work yet.
How can I solve this?

Comment: implement EnvironmentAware

Comment: Or you can use @Conditional for property, instead of defining it as a field, so that it gets registered only when the property is false

Comment: I tried the @COnditionalOnProperty before and the bean was loaded anyways

Answer (score 0):

Implement `EnvironmentAware` interface and get the property from the environment.

```
public class DatabaseExclusionFilter implements AutoConfigurationImportFilter, EnvironmentAware {

    private static final Set<String> DATABASE_BEANS_SKIP = new HashSet<>(
        Arrays.asList("org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration",
                "org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration"));

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public boolean[] match(String[] autoConfigurationClasses, AutoConfigurationMetadata autoConfigurationMetadata) {
        List<Boolean> excludeBeans = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!Boolean.parseBoolean(environment.getProperty("database.enabled")))) {
            excludeBeans = match(Arrays.asList(autoConfigurationClasses));
        }
        return convertToPrimitiveArray(excludeBeans);
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```